# About synchronized keyword?

Tags: java

ReentrantLock is not the point, and the key is the synchronized code block. There's a high probability of consecutive "AAA get,".

```
public class ReentrantLockTest {
    private static final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(()->test(),"AAA").start();
        new Thread(()->test(),"BBB").start();
        new Thread(()->test(),"CCC").start();
        new Thread(()->test(),"DDD").start();
    }
    public static void test() {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 3;i++) {
            try{
                synchronized (lock) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" get,");
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {

            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Result：

```
AAA get,         
AAA get,      
AAA get,    
DDD get,     
DDD get,     
DDD get,  
CCC get,    
CCC get,   
CCC get,   
BBB get,    
BBB get,  
BBB get,
```

This seems to make it easier to get the lock if the lock has just been released, so why? Is this a compiler optimization?

Comment: That is just nondeterministic behavior.

Comment: RenetrantLock is not meant to be used with synchronized keyword (to obtain object monitor). Check [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html). Your code will (mis)behave in same way when you replace `Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);` with `Object lock = new Object();`

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my word,RenetrantLock  is not the  point ,and the key is  Synchronized code block, There's a high probability of consecutive "AAA get,"

Comment: You should replace the ReentrantLock with an Object and fix the title of this question. You've made it somewhat confusing. Essentially the behavior is not defined and you have a race condition. It will probably change on different platforms, but I am also surprised you get such consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

> This seems to make it easier to get the lock if the lock has just been released,so why?

Look at it this way: Imagine that thread would change every time synchronized block is reached. That would not be very effective (since there is cost to changing threads).

In your code, current thread does not indicate that other threads can run except inside synchronized block where it still holds the lock.

This can be seen when you will move sleep outside of synchronized block:

```
try{
     synchronized (lock) {
         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" get,");
     }
     TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
 }catch(InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }finally {

 }
```

result in my case was:

> AAA get,
>   BBB get,
>   CCC get,
>   DDD get,
>   CCC get,
>   AAA get,
>   DDD get,
>   BBB get,
>   DDD get,
>   AAA get,
>   BBB get,
>   CCC get,

so thread changed every time, since current thread indicated that it wants to stop (call to sleep) and other thread was available.

In the end JVM will decide to swap threads even without calling sleep, for example with 100 iterations:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 100;i++) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" get,");
    } 
}
```

In my case i did get:

> AAA get,
>   AAA get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   AAA get,
>   AAA get,
>   AAA get,
>   AAA get,
>   AAA get,....

and again:

> CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   DDD get,
>   DDD get,
>   DDD get,
>   DDD get,
>   DDD get,
>   DDD get,
>   DDD get,
>   DDD get,
>   DDD get,
>   DDD get,
>   DDD get,
>   DDD get,
>   DDD get,
>   DDD get,
>   DDD get,
>   DDD get,
>   DDD get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   AAA get,
>   AAA get,
>   AAA get,
>   AAA get,
>   AAA get,
>   AAA get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get,
>   CCC get, ....

So threads are changed but timing and order is not guaranteed at all.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to note before I dive in:

- The behavior of the Java thread scheduler is not specified.  Whatever is actually going on here is within the "envelope" of correct behavior.
- Your test code is not testing the behavior of `ReentrantLock` here.  You are *actually* using the lock instance as a primitive monitor or mutex.  You don't use `synchronized` with a `Lock` object.

---

It appears that on the platform that you are running your code, the last executed thread does seem to get preference .... up to a point.  I got similar behavior to what your reported, but when the thread loops were longer, I did see switching.  By contrast, Piro sees different behavior.  (I would put this done to probably caused by OS differences.)

So what is going on here?  Well the actual behavior is determined in part by the operating system's native thread scheduler implementation, and in part by what is actually going on.

A typical native thread scheduler does not implement "fair" scheduling by default.  If two native threads have the same priority there are no guarantees that each will get a fair share.  Instead, a scheduler may optimize to minimize context switch overheads, or scheduling overheads.  So different behavior of different OSes is to be expected.

The other thing to consider is the behavior of the threads in this example.  The thread that is holding the monitor does the following:

1. It wakes up from the `sleep`
2. It releases the monitor
3. It unparks another thread
4. It attempts to reacquire the monitor

The thread that was unparked also attempts to acquire the monitor.

So, the question is which will the race to acquire the monitor?  It would appear that the thread that was originally holding the monitor will usually win (at least, on my machine).

Why?  It is hard to say:

- It could be that the thread returns from the unpark syscall before the other thread is scheduled.
- It could be that the unparked thread is typically hampered by TLAB misses or memory cache misses.
- It could be other things; e.g. things that I haven't thought of.

But any way, this is unlikely to be a deliberate design decision to prioritize one thread over the other.  It probably just happens that way.

(The actual implementation of monitors in the JVM is is very complicated.  Take a look at `synchronizer.cpp` and `objectMonitor.cpp` ... in the OpenJDK 11 codebase.  That only deals with the JVM side.)

---

> Is this compiler optimization?

I don't think so.  The JIT compiler does optimize monitor entry and exit sequences, but that only deals with "fast path" entry / exit when the monitor is uncontended.  In this example the monitor is contended.